# Why Installing Kali Linux metapackage, returns "Temporary failure resolving 'http.kali.org'"

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, kali-linux, wsl2

I was installing all Kali Linuxx metapackages with:

```
sudo apt install -y kali-linux-everything
```

Since it was very large I had to disconnect the network and re-run the command again (I had limited network plan). It worked for 6 days and was almost finished. But today I got this:

[image]

I'm running this command from kali-linux distro in wsl2.
With `--fix-missing` I get the same error. Then I ran `apt-get update`. And got this:

[image]

To check if there is problem with network I ran `curl https://http.kali.org` and got this:

[image]

But when ran from command prompt it works:

[image]

What is wrong with Kali Linux terminal? How do I fix it?

Comment: DNS problem inside the Kali VM.

Comment: @mtak If so how do I fix it?

Comment: I don't want to come off as snobbish, but if you're running Kali, you should really know how to change DNS settings on a Linux box. If you don't, you have no business running Kali: https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/.

Comment: While there are answers that suggested you change the DNS, the reality is this all sounds like an intermittent networking issue. Meaning if you wait a few minutes, sometimes longer, the DNS issue resolves itself. I think changing DNS resolvers is an okay idea, but one might up scrambling to make changes that end up doing nothing because even if your DNS is fine, it doesn’t mean the DNS on the Kali servers side is fine.

Answer (score 3):

Edit the `/etc/resolv.conf` file and change it from:

```
nameserver 172.24.0.1
```

To another DNS service like [the one CloudFlare provides](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/what-is-1.1.1.1/):

```
nameserver 1.1.1.1
```

Or the IP of another DNS server of your choice.

Comment: Suggesting changing DNS servers is a decent idea. But if the source Kali Linux server is suffering from intermittent issues, then endlessly switching DNS servers won’t solve the issue. PS: Please be sure to clearly explain that `1.1.1.1` is CloudFlare’s DNS server. Just asking someone to change a DNS value to some number is not a great idea.

Comment: Thanks this helped me to fix my issue.